# Getting mysql result of item update

Tags: php, mysql

How i can alter my php code, so it can echo "if the item has just been created or updated?"

```
$query_item_create = "INSERT INTO `item` (`category_id`, `id`) VALUES ('$catid', '$id')";
$query_item_update = "UPDATE `item` SET `date`='$date',`info`='$info' WHERE `id`='$id'";
mysql_query($query_item_create);
mysql_query($query_item_update);
```

Comment: Presumably, if you know the ID then it is an update. If you don't have an ID then it's an insert.

Comment: i always know the $id but it may be already in the database! Thats why i use both commands! The first one to create the row if it doesnt exist and the second one to update the valuable info

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here explains better: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

```
$affected = mysql_affected_rows();
if($affected > 0)
   echo "row was updated/inserted";
else
   echo "No rows were ....";
```